# removing duplicates from two 2 dimensional list

Tags: list, python-3.x, unique, nested-lists

i searched for a solution to remove deplicates from two 2d list in python i couldn't find so here my question:
i have two lists, for example

```
[[1,2],[3,5],[4,4],[5,7]]

[[1,3],[4,4],[3,5],[3,5],[5,6]]
```

Expected result:

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[5,7],[5,6]]
```

I want to remove list inside on the lists that match EXACTLY the values of the other list.

my script:

```
def filter2dim(firstarray, secondarray):
    unique = []
    for i in range(len(firstarray)):
       temp=firstarray[i]
       for j in range(len(secondarray)):
           if(temp == secondarray[j]):
              break
           elif(j==(len(secondarray)-1)):
               unique.append(temp)
    for i in range(len(secondarray)):
       temp=secondarray[i]
       for j in range(len(firstarray)):
           if(temp == firstarray[j]):
              break
           elif(j==(len(firstarray)-1)):
               unique.append(secondarray[i])
    return
```

Please if you fix it and explain what you did it will be greateful.
Thank you, Best Regards

Comment: Why `[1, 2]` is not in the result?

Comment: oh yeah and [1,2] sorry

Comment: How does `[5,6]` get included in the dupes?

Comment: Is it important for you to keep the order?

Comment: just to mention my script is working on small lists, but when there is a big list it mixes up.

Comment: i want the unique values between the two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your 2-item lists with tuples and you can use set operations (because tuples are immutable and lists not, and set items must be immutable):

```
a = {(1,2),(3,5),(4,4),(5,7)}
b = {(1,3),(4,4),(3,5),(3,5),(5,6)}
print(a.symmetric_difference(b)) # {(1, 2), (5, 7), (5, 6), (1, 3)}
```

Note this also removes duplicates within each list because they are sets, and order is ignored.

If you need to programatically convert your lists into tuples, a list comprehension works just fine:

```
list_a = [[1,2],[3,5],[4,4],[5,7]]
set_a = {(i, j) for i, j in list_a}
print(set_a) # {(1, 2), (4, 4), (5, 7), (3, 5)}
```

Comment: hmm sorry i'm not very familliar with python how to swtich them to tuples?

Comment: @user2597549 Just edited the question with that answer.

Comment: okay could you please give me some time to test it. thank you

Comment: a simple question, if the first list is empty will it cause any problem ?

Comment: If one set is empty, `symmetric_difference` will return all values in the other set. If both are empty, it returns the empty set. I believe this is reasonable behavior, but please check if it makes sense in your context. And since it's symmetric, it makes no difference which one is the first.

Comment: Hello, i need to switch back the tuple into the list how it can be done ? thank you.

Comment: You do the same, but with lists instead of sets and tuples: `list_a = [[i, j] for i, j in set_a]`

Answer (score 1):

Your script works fine for me, just add: `return unique`

Comment: yeah i know, but sometimes i have lists will 1000 values it mixes up

Answer (score 0):

Turn the first list into a `dict`:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 4], [5, 7]]
b = [[1, 3], [4, 4], [3, 5], [3, 5], [5, 6]]

filt = dict(a)
result = [el for el in b if el[0] in filt and el[0] == filt[el[0]]]
```

Alternatively, turn the first list into a set of tuples, and just check for membership:

```
filt = set(map(tuple, a))
result = [el for el in b if tuple(el) in filt]
```

Both of these solutions avoid iterating through the first list more than once, because `dict` and `set` lookups are O(1).

Comment: I believe `Counter` is a better hash-table based structure for this sort of things, i.e. counting :)