# Get unique values from second of two 2 dimensinal lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, unique

I asked about finding non-duplicated items from two lists in my [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919898/removing-duplicates-from-two-2-dimensional-list) and received the answer.

I have now realised I have a different requirement but can't adapt my code or the answers I got there.

I have two list which is for example

```
List1= [[1,2],[3,5],[4,4],[5,7]]
List2= [[1,3],[4,4],[3,5],[3,5],[5,6]]
Result= [[1,3],[5,6]]
```

I want the unique values from second list only (not both)

My script:

```
def filter2dim(firstarray, secondarray):
    unique = []
    for i in range(len(firstarray)):
       temp=firstarray[i]
       for j in range(len(secondarray)):
           if(temp == secondarray[j]):
              break
           elif(j==(len(secondarray)-1)):
               unique.append(temp)
    for i in range(len(secondarray)):
       temp=secondarray[i]
       for j in range(len(firstarray)):
           if(temp == firstarray[j]):
              break
           elif(j==(len(firstarray)-1)):
               unique.append(secondarray[i])
    return unique
```

This doesn't quite do what I want - can anyone suggest what I could do to make it return only values unique to the second list?

Comment: Why do you still use *the exact same code* as in your old question? Why don’t you try to use one of the answers from there and amend them for your changed requirement? Instead, you post an *identical* question agian but with a changed expected result and want *us* to do all the work again. Please try to solve this on your own now.

Comment: i did, they does the same as mine..., i need only unique values from second list

Comment: i tried all the codes, they does what i wanted at first, thanks to you guys, but after implementing the code i noticed that i need the unique values from second list only, i'm new to stackoverflow so i though that maybe i need to re-ask the question, sorry.

Comment: *“I thought that maybe I need to re-ask the question”* – Yes, that’s usually fine, but you should show some progress between those questions. The way this looks is more like you ignored everything that was answered in the old question, and you start in the *exact same way* again with altered expected results. It’s **your** job to learn from the answers of the old question and try to get to the new result using what you have learned.

Comment: yeah, i'm sorry thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Sorry if i made an issue, but i found an answer, after implementing

```
    a = {(1,2),(3,5),(4,4),(5,7)}
    b = {(1,3),(4,4),(3,5),(3,5),(5,6)}
    print(a.symmetric_difference(b)) # {(1, 2), (1, 3), (5, 6), (5, 7)}
```

Suggested in the first question i asked, i went to google and searched what does symmetric_difference does and if there is any alternatives, and found the answer in the following https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html which is `a.difference(b)`

```
    a = {(1,2),(3,5),(4,4),(5,7)}
    b = {(1,3),(4,4),(3,5),(3,5),(5,6)}
    print(a.difference(b)) # {(1, 2),(5, 7)}

    a = {(1,2),(3,5),(4,4),(5,7)}
    b = {(1,3),(4,4),(3,5),(3,5),(5,6)}
    print(b.difference(a)) # {(1,3),(5,6)}
```

thank you, best regards.

Comment: I recommend you accept this answer as it obviously worked for you :)  There is no problem with [adding your own answer and accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here - glad you worked out your problem!

Comment: Thank you, i usually keep trying to fix all my problems even tho i post them here :).

Comment: Great.  I've also edited your question a bit - just to emphasise the way that it is different to your previous question.

Comment: yeah, I'm not good at explaining things,thank you again.